# Taking a list of lists and generating all variants with one element replaced

Tags: haskell

I have types for a two-dimensional map of characters:

```
type Row = [Char]
type Mappy = [Row]
```

I'd like to write a function that takes a `Mappy` like:

```
[['o','o'],['o','o']]
```

and generates a list of all `Mappy`s with a single 'o' element replaced with 'i':

```
[ [['i','o'],['o','o']]
, [['o','i'],['o','o']]
, [['o','o'],['i','o']]
, [['o','o'],['o','i']]
]
```

Here's what I've tried:  I think I need to use the map function, because I need to go over each element, but I don't know how, because a map function doesn't keep track of the position it is working on.

```
type Row = [Char]
type Mappy = [Row]

func :: Mappy -> [Mappy]
func a = map (map someFunc a) a

someFunc :: Mappy -> Char -> Mappy
someFunc a b = if b == "o"
               then undefined
               else a
```

Obviously, I should change the `undefined`, but i have no idea how. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should change a lot more than only the undefined...

Comment: I don't think you are on the right track. I'd try to start by writing a function that, given a row, computes the list of all possible variant rows.

Comment: Hi, @BaasBartMans.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I think this is a neat question, but it was in danger of being closed.  I tried to rewrite it to make it clearer.  Feel free to edit it further (or change things back) if you think I misunderstood what you were asking.

Comment: Also, can you explain what your function should do it you give it a `Mappy` like `[['o','x'],['o','o']]`.  Should it generate a list of four variants, with `'i'` replacing each of the four elements, or should it only generate the three variants where `'o'` is replaced with `'i'`, so the `'x'` is never changed?

Comment: @K.A.Buhr only the o should be replaced indeed, so i need to do some checking indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zippers are great, and there's an interesting blog post about
implementing [Conway's Game of Life using zippers and comonads in Haskell](https://samtay.github.io/posts/comonadic-game-of-life.html).  On the other
hand, if this is still your first week learning Haskell, you might
want to save Comonads for Thursday, right?

Here's another approach that uses simple recursion and list
comprehensions and no complex Haskell features.

First, imagine we have an awesome function:

```
varyOne :: (a -> [a]) -> [a] -> [[a]]
varyOne = undefined
```

that works as follows.  Given a function `f` that produces zero or
more variants of an element `a`, the function call `varyOne f xs`
generates all variants of the list `xs` that result from taking
exactly one element of `xs`, say `x` in the middle of the list, and replacing it with all the
variants given by `f x`.

This function is surprisingly flexible.  It can generate the list of all variants resulting from forcibly replacing an element by a constant:

```
> varyOne (\x -> [3]) [1,2,3,4]
[[3,2,3,4],[1,3,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,3]]
```

By returning a singleton variant for a specific value and an empty list of variants for other values, it can generate all variants that replace an `'o'` with an `'i'` while suppressing the "variants" where no replacement is possible:

```
> let varyRow = varyOne (\c -> if c == 'o' then ['i'] else [])
> varyRow "ooxo"
["ioxo","oixo","ooxi"]
```

and, because `varyRow` itself generates variants of a row, it can be used with `varyOne` to generate variants of tables where a particular *row* has been replaced by its possible variants:

```
> varyOne varyRow ["ooo","oox","ooo"]
[["ioo","oox","ooo"],["oio","oox","ooo"],["ooi","oox","ooo"],
 ["ooo","iox","ooo"],["ooo","oix","ooo"],
 ["ooo","oox","ioo"],["ooo","oox","oio"],["ooo","oox","ooi"]]
```

It turns out that this awesome function is surprisingly easy to write:

```
varyOne :: (a -> [a]) -> [a] -> [[a]]
varyOne f (x:xs)
    = [y:xs | y <- f x] ++ [x:ys | ys <- varyOne f xs]
varyOne _ []     = []
```

The first list comprehension generates all the variants for the current element.  The second list comprehension generates variants that involve changes to the right of the current element using a recursive `varyOne` call.

Given `varyOne`, we can define:

```
replaceOne :: Char -> Char -> Mappy -> [Mappy]
replaceOne old new = varyOne (varyOne rep1)
  where rep1 x = if x == old then [new] else []
```

and:

```
> replaceOne 'o' 'i' ["ooo","oox","ooo"]
[["ioo","oox","ooo"],["oio","oox","ooo"],["ooi","oox","ooo"]
,["ooo","iox","ooo"],["ooo","oix","ooo"]
,["ooo","oox","ioo"],["ooo","oox","oio"],["ooo","oox","ooi"]]
```

is probably the function you're looking for.

If you prefer to unconditionally replace a single element with `i`, no matter what the old element was, then this will work:

```
> varyOne (varyOne (const ['i'])) ["ooo","oox","ooo"]
[["ioo","oox","ooo"],["oio","oox","ooo"],["ooi","oox","ooo"]
,["ooo","iox","ooo"],["ooo","oix","ooo"],["ooo","ooi","ooo"]
,["ooo","oox","ioo"],["ooo","oox","oio"],["ooo","oox","ooi"]]
```

Comment: This is a much better answer for someone new to haskell

Comment: Yess thanks, this is just what i needed :)

Answer (score 2):

What you want, young BaasBartMans, is a Zipper.

```
data Zipper a = Zipper [a] a [a]

ofList :: [a] -> Maybe (Zipper a)
ofList [] = Nothing
ofList (a:as) = Just (Zipper [] a as)
```

A zipper gives you the context for a position in a list, so you
can easily modify them one at a time, step forward and backward and such.

We can recover a list from a zipper:

```
instance Foldable Zipper where
  foldr f c (Zipper ls a rs) = foldl' (flip f) (f a (foldr f c rs)) ls
```

We can modify every position in a Zipper simultaneously:

```
instance Functor Zipper where
  fmap f (Zipper ls a rs) = Zipper (fmap f ls) (f a) (fmap f rs)
```

Or just the focused element:

```
here :: Functor f => (a -> f a) -> Zipper a -> f (Zipper a)
here f (Zipper ls a rs) = fmap (\a' -> Zipper ls a' rs) (f a)
```

And as a `Zipper` is a `Comonad`, we can modify each element in context:

```
instance Comonad Zipper where
  extract (Zipper _ a _) = a
  extend f z@(Zipper ls a rs) = Zipper ls' a' rs' where
    a' = f z
    ls' = unfoldr (fmap (\z' -> (f z', z')) . goLeft) z
    rs' = unfoldr (fmap (\z' -> (f z', z')) . goRight) z
```

Using that, we can build a function that modifies each element of a list in context:

```
everywhere :: Alternative f => (a -> f a) -> [a] -> f [a]
everywhere f as = case ofList as of
  Nothing -> pure []
  Just z  -> asum $ extend (fmap toList . here f) z
```

Which works for simple lists:

```
λ everywhere (\a -> [a+1]) [10,20,30]
[[11,20,30]
,[10,21,30]
,[10,20,31]]
```

And nested lists:

```
λ everywhere (everywhere (\a -> [a+1])) [[10], [20,20], [30,30,30]]
[[[11],[20,20],[30,30,30]]
,[[10],[21,20],[30,30,30]]
,[[10],[20,21],[30,30,30]]
,[[10],[20,20],[31,30,30]]
,[[10],[20,20],[30,31,30]]
,[[10],[20,20],[30,30,31]]]
```

Comment: A zipper seemed to do the job indeed, thanks